# Previewing OpenGLES Render Buffers under Android

Tags: eclipse, opengl-es, eclipse-plugin

I've started to play a bit with the Frame Buffer Objects and Render Buffers in OpenGLES. One thing that bugs me out is that I'm not able to see what data is currently in my Render Buffer instance, or simply put - what I've drawn within. I know that I could possibly draw my data into the texture and then simply sample it onto the rectangle, but I don't want to do that. Maybe somebody already used or is aware of some sort of a plugin, preferably an Eclipse plugin, or eventually an application that would present me with the graphical data of the Render Buffer of my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my question myself, there are some tools dedicated for NVIDIA Tegra chipsets which are really helpful when dealing with problems within the OpenGL scope (PerfHUD ES for example)